# Limit number of checked checkboxes using iCheck

Tags: jquery, checkbox, icheck

I'm using iCheck to style checkboxes and I'm having trouble using this along side validation. Basically I need to allow 3 checkboxes to be checked at a time and prevent further boxes from being checked.

I've tried using this:

```
$("#modal1").on("change", function()
{
  var limit = 3,
      checkboxes = $(this).find("input:checkbox"),
      valid = checkboxes.filter(":checked").length >= limit;

    checkboxes.not(":checked").attr("disabled", valid);
    $('input').iCheck('update');
});
```

It works without iCheck as seen below, but I can't get iCheck to update.

http://jsfiddle.net/hUdrF/4/

Answer (score 4):

I up adding `.on("ifToggled"` plus SpaceDog's code, which solved the problem.

```
$("#modal1").on("ifToggled", function() {
    checkboxes = $(this).find("input:checkbox");  
    if (checkboxes.filter(":checked").length >= 3) { 
        checkboxes.not(":checked").iCheck('disable'); 
    } else { 
        checkboxes.not(":checked").iCheck('enable');
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the iCheck update method isn't seeing the change to the disabled attribute. You could try the native iCheck method for disabling a checkbox:

```
if (checkboxes.filter(":checked").length >= limit) { 
    checkboxes.not(":checked").iCheck('disable'); 
} else {
    checkboxes.not(":checked").iCheck('enable'); 
}
```

Comment: Hmm, does this look right?

`$("#modal1").on("change", function()
 {
   var limit = 3
   checkboxes = $(this).find("input:checkbox")
    if (checkboxes.filter(":checked").length >= limit) { 
   checkboxes.not(":checked").iCheck('disable'); 
  } else {
   checkboxes.not(":checked").iCheck('enable'); 
  }
});`

Comment: Looks right, although I'd put the semicolons in to show the end of the command. `$("#modal1").on("change", function() { 
    var limit = 3;
    checkboxes = $(this).find("input:checkbox");
    if (checkboxes.filter(":checked").length >= limit) {
        checkboxes.not(":checked").iCheck('disable'); 
    }
    else { 
        checkboxes.not(":checked").iCheck('enable'); 
    } 
});`

Answer (score 0):

make some changes in code

```
    $("#modal1").on("change", function()
    {
    var limit = 2;
    $('.check').on('ifChanged', function(event) {
        checkboxes = $('.icheck-list').find("input:checkbox");
        if (checkboxes.filter(":checked").length >= limit) {
            checkboxes.not(":checked").iCheck('disable');
        } else {
            checkboxes.not(":checked").iCheck('enable');
        }
    });
    });
```